# Trust region algorithm mystery

Tags: numerical-optimization

I was watching the trust region algorithm implementation in the dlib code, `optimization_trust_region.h`, where it is stated that

> "This is an implementation of algorithm 4.3 (Trust Region Subproblem) from
>   the book Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright. Some of the details 
>   are also from Practical Methods of Optimization by Fletcher."

I started to compare both algorithms and found mismatch which I can't explain. The heart of the algorithm is the 1-d root-finding procedure for some scalar function $\varphi$. The formulae for the iteration step mismatch and that's how.

We have:
$$
  \varphi(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\Delta} - \frac{1}{\|p\|} = \frac{1}{\Delta} - \big(p^T p\big)^{-1/2}.
$$
Hence,
$$
  \varphi'(\lambda) = \frac12 \big(p^T p\big)^{-3/2} \cdot 2 p^T p' = \frac{p^T p'}{\|p\|^3}.
$$
What about $p' \equiv \dfrac{dp}{d\lambda}$? We have
$$
  (B + \lambda I)p = -g,
$$
and this means that, differentiating by $\lambda$, we get
$$
  p + (B + \lambda I)p' = 0.
$$
Remember that in algorithm 4.1 we factorize the matrix $(B + \lambda I)$ via Cholesky decomposition: $(B + \lambda I) = R^T R$, and this means that
$$
  R^T R p' = -p,
$$
and if we denote $Rp' = q$ (which means that $q$ is the solution of the equation $R^T q = -p$), then we have
$$
  p^T p' = (p, p') = -(R^T R p', p') = -(Rp', Rp') = -\|Rp'\|^2 = -\|q\|^2.
$$
Combining all this together we come to the conclusion that
$$
  -\frac{\varphi(\lambda)}{\varphi'(\lambda)} =
  -\frac{\|p\| - \Delta}{\Delta \|p\|}\cdot \frac{\|p\|^3}{-\|q\|^2} =
  \bigg(\frac{\|p\|}{\|q\|}\bigg)^2\bigg(\frac{\|p\| - \Delta}{\Delta}\bigg)
$$
in perfect accordance with the page~87 of the book.

If we turn to the dlib code however, we see that: a) their $R$ is our $R^T$ (because their Cholesky factorization looks $RR^T$ instead of $R^T R$); and b) they define the vector $q$ differently, as the solution of the equation $Rq = -g$ which means that their $q = R^T p$.

So, if we use Nocedal-Wright notation, we can compare the two approaches:
$$
\begin{array}{l|c|c}
 & \text{Nocedal-Wright} & \text{dlib library} \\
\hline
\text{Eq. for } p: & R^T Rp = -g & \text{the same} \\
\hline
\text{Eq. for } q: & R^T q = -p & R^T q = -g \\
\hline
\text{Definition of } q: & q = Rp' & q = Rp \\
\hline
\text{Iteration step:} & \bigg(\dfrac{\|p_{\ell}\|}{\|q_{\ell}\|}\bigg)^2\bigg(\dfrac{\|p_{\ell}\| - \Delta}{\Delta}\bigg) 
                & \bigg(\dfrac{\|q_{\ell}\|}{\|p_{\ell}\|}\bigg)^2\bigg(\dfrac{\|p_{\ell}\| - \Delta}{\Delta}\bigg) \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

How could one make sense of the discrepancy? Could both approaches be correct, and how?